# Comparing date in PHP

Tags: php, date

I am working on a project where i have to compare the expiration date of a medical certificate with the current date.
If the expiration date is more than two months from the current date I should set a green icon into the user page; if there are less than two months to expiration date I'd set a yellow icon otherwise, if the expiration date has passed, I'd show a red icon.

To perform the above action I wrote the following code:

```
$medical = new DateTime($data->medical_expiration);
$today = new DateTime();

$compare = $today->modify('+2 month');

if($compare < $medical) {
    $this->data['check_medical'] = 'success';
} elseif($compare >= $medical && $today <= $medical) {
    $this->data['check_medical'] = 'warning';
} else {
    $this->data['check_medical'] = 'alarm';
}
```

I thought that the else if block should set the icon to yellow...but it doesn't work. I get a red icon when the expiration date is less then two months from today.
What's wrong with the code?
Thanks a lot for any feedback or suggestion to improve the above code ( I don't like to many if-else block )

Comment: ["The function modifies this object."](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php)

Comment: Have you tried inspecting `$today` to see what it contains after you've modified it?

Comment: Setup you compare like this `$compare = new DateTime(); $compare->modify('+2 month');`

Comment: Or even `$compare = (new DateTime())->modify('+2 month');`

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction ... I completely missed to check the value of $today after added 2 months. Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function compare($compare, $medical, $today){

 if($compare < $medical) { return "success"; }
 if($compare >= $medical && $today <= $medical) { return "warning"; } 

 return "alarm";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... the function really improve the code.